# Delay form submission after preventDefault()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to attach an event listener on each form element, then check if they are submitted. I do not want the form to submit, but instead wait for 1 second before it does so. While the form has been submitted, I want it to `console.log()` the result from the form. The code below should work, but it does not:

```
$("form").each(function() {
    $(this).on("submit", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var form = $(this);
        setTimeout(function() {
            form.submit();
        }, 1000);
        var data = $(this).serialize();
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

The problem I get is either it keeps the event listener up, so it basically runs into an infinite loop or it doesn't submit the form. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: For all of you downvoting this: Why? I know I should not introduce latency to the form submission, but this is for my own project and I am perfectly fine with waiting a second.

Comment: I mean why? Why would you make your web site less responsive? This sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: try to distinguish the submit you need from the one you dont.

Comment: @jidexl21 I need to hit every submit on the page, so that's not an option.

Comment: Please tell me why you're downvoting a question that no one seems to be able to answer. Why I do this and why I shouldn't do this does not belong on Stackoverflow. I know I shouldn't do this in a working environment, but I still need an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var submitted = false;
$("form").each(function() {
    $(this).on("submit", function(e) {
        if(!submitted) {
            e.preventDefault();
            setTimeout(() => {
                $(this).submit();
            }, 1000);
            var data = $(this).serialize();
            console.log(data);
            submitted = true;
        }
    });
});
```

This works as it should. I was hoping for a better solution, but if it works it works.

Comment: You've now introduced a race condition. What happens if I double click the submit button?

Comment: @Liam I appreciate your thoughts on this process, but don't worry about my problems. Let's just assume the page reloads on every submit.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `form` is the jQuery object, so `form.submit()` runs the jQuery submit handler, and causes the infinite loop. You want to call the browser's native submit code. Do that with:

```
var form = $(this).get(0);
```

This sets `form` to the DOM element rather than a jQuery object, and `form.submit()` will submit the form without going through the jQuery handler.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("form").each(function() {
    $(this).on("submit", function(e) {
        if(!$(this).hasClass("submitted")) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var form = $(this);
            setTimeout(function() {
                form.submit();
            }, 1000);
            var data = $(this).serialize();
            console.log(data);
            $(this).addClass("submitted");
        }
    });
});
```

You could try something like this, if you really need to do so.

Comment: Doesn't submit the form.

Comment: Yup, there was an error in the syntax, i fixed that now

Comment: Explain what you changed and why, don't just dump a bunch of code.

Comment: Well, one of the brackets in the `if` statement was a `(` instead of `)`. I guess i missed that when i first wrote the answer

Comment: some people here have a fetish to downvote answers , I believe.

Answer (score 0):

```
     bool someflag=true    
     $("form").each(function() {
        $(this).on("submit", function(e) {
        if (someflag){        
                e.preventDefault();
                someflag=false;
        }
                var form = $(this);
                setTimeout(function() {
                    form.submit();
                }, 1000);
                var data = $(this).serialize();
                console.log(data);
            });
        });
```

Comment: Doesn't submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will work. The form submittion is delayed one second. You will have to remove the timeout after the form is submitted.

```
$("form").each(function() {

    $(this).on("submit", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var form = $(this);
        var data = $(this).serialize();
        setTimeout(function() {
          console.log(data);
          form.submit();
        }, 1000);
    });

});
```

Comment: Where does this submit the form?

Comment: @Barmar Whoops. Fixed :)